# Numpy fast for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list named "y" with 8 numpy arrays of the shape (180000,)
Now I want to create a new numpy array named "Collision" with the same shape that counts how many values ​​of y are not 0. See the following example:

```
import numpy as np
collisions = np.zeros(len(y[0]), dtype=np.uint8)
for yi in y:
    collisions[np.where(yi > 0)] += 1
```

The calculation of this function takes a relatively long time. Is there a faster implementation to do this?

Comment: are you trying to count how many elements are greater than zero for each element, 0 to 180000 ? Although the code is not optimal, it should not take so long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why your calculation takes so long, hope this helps to clarify, for example your list of array is like this:

```
import numpy as np
y = [np.random.normal(0,1,180000) for i in range(8)]
```

Running your code, it works ok:

```
collisions = np.zeros(len(y[0]), dtype=np.uint8)
for yi in y:
    collisions[np.where(yi > 0)] += 1

collisions
array([4, 2, 4, ..., 4, 4, 5], dtype=uint8)
```

You can do it a bit faster like this, basically making your list of arrays a matrix and doing a row sum of >0, but I don't see the problem with that above:

```
(np.array(y)>0).sum(axis=0)

array([4, 2, 4, ..., 4, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

# simulating your data by randomly generating numbers in [-0.5, 0.5)
y = np.random.rand(8, 180_000) - 0.5
print(y.shape) # (8, 180000)

collisions = np.sum(y > 0, axis=0, dtype=np.uint8)
print(collisions.shape) # (180000,)
print(collisions) # [4 4 4 ... 1 6 7]
```